# How to make a migration in laravel module?

Tags: laravel, module, eloquent, laravel-migrations

In my Laravel project, I use **nwidart** package for making modules. Now I want to add `deleted_at` column to an existing model. I should make a new migration in my module. 
How can I do this?

Here is the package documentation: 
https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v4/advanced-tools/artisan-commands

I want some thing like this for module:

`php artisan make:migration add_soft_deletes_to_user_table --table="users"`

Comment: Do you need the data in your `users` table? Can it be refreshed?

Comment: Yes, I need data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this command:

```
php artisan module:make-migration add_soft_deletes_to_users_table <ModuleName>
```

Then do not forget to use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait on your `User` model.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model {

use SoftDeletes;

}
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked. I just add module's name at end of the command.

Comment: php artisan module:make-migration <migration_name> <ModuleName>